# VHDL: Clock switching using BUFGMUX

Tags: vhdl, resolution, clock, fpga

I am currently trying to do a selection between resolutions using two switches on my Basys3. I use a record type array to store the parameters of two resolutions (800x600, 1024x768) and assigned each one to a different switch. Also, using the clock wizard of Vivado, I generate two separate clocks (40MHz, 65MHz) according to the two resolutions. Now my question is, how do I use BUFGMUX to select between those clocks as to generate the one I need for the resolution currently in use?

This is what I have written so far (Is it correct, can it be improved?):

```
architecture Behavioral of Resolutions is

type Timings is
record
cstHorAL, cstHorFP, cstHorPW, cstHorBP  : integer;
cstHorTotSize                           : integer;
cstVerAL, cstVerFP, cstVerPW, cstVerBP  : integer;
cstVerTotSize                           : integer;
end record;

type Timings_array is array (0 to 1) of Timings;

constant resolutions : Timings_array :=
(
(800, 40, 128, 88, 1056, 600, 1, 4, 23, 628),
(1024,24, 136, 160, 1344, 768, 3, 6, 28, 806)
);

signal res : Timings;

begin

process
begin
if (CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1') then
case SW is
    when "1000000000000000" => res <= resolutions(0);
    when "0100000000000000" => res <= resolutions(1);
end case;
LED <= SW;
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I do not see how this is related with record structure. I guess it is FPGA question. I also think that you need a wait statement in your process.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I would recommend a sensitivity list: `process (clk)` instead of `process`.

Comment: Thank you. Valentin, could you please examplify how to inculde a wait statement? :)

Comment: The way Matthew advised or `wait until CLK = '1'`, I guess, in place of `if-clk-event-equals-1`. I prefer wait until clk = 1 because it eliminates one level of nesting.

Comment: Please take a look at the [7 series libraries guide for hdl designs](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/7series_hdl.pdf) The BUFGMUX is used more or less like a 2:1 multiplexer.